# Error using the Library on a Windows Server 2008 SP2 64-bit

Tags: c#, 64-bit, fdf

I developed an application (C# Framework 4) using the fdf toolkit running on a **32 bit** server and everything works well.

I have migrated this application to a Windows Server 2008 SP2 **64 Bits** and sometimes this application gives me this error:

> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800703FA): Retrieving
>   the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {CB830891-2E18-11D1-B8CF-00A0C9259304} failed due to the following
>   error: 800703fa Illegal operation attempted on a registry key that has
>   been marked for deletion.

After this error, I recycle the website pool and the application runs well again.

Details of the application:

1. Registered the libraries FDF.dll, FDFACX.dll and FDFTK.dll in c:\windows\SysWOW64.
2. Enabled  in the web site pool the property 'Enable 32-Bit Applications'
3. Enabled 'Do not forcefully unload the user registry at user logoff ' property in the Group Policy Editor

Could you help me?

Thanks¡¡¡

Answer (score 0):

What is the target platform you are building your application for?  It will be either x86, x64, Itanium, or most likely "Any CPU".

You can try setting it to x86, that way you know everything is built to use the 32-bit version of .Net.  Alternatively you can run [CorFlags](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164699%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) on your assembly(ies) to change it to x86 without recompiling.

If that doesn't solve the problem then we will need more code :)

Comment: The application is compiled under 'Any CPU'. I'll try user x86 option, thanks¡¡

Comment: Pending until june, this application only runs in that month, cross the fingers¡¡

Comment: The project was cancelled, so sorry, I can't answer to this question

Comment: he project was cancelled because I have bought libreries of Aspose and CETE for this purpose , so sorry, I can't answer to this question.

Comment: Ahh, PDF libraries - so worth the money.

Comment: At least, we are using Aspose library for do it. Thanks to all¡¡